# python for-loop slower each iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, performance, memory-bandwidth

I am trying to optimize some python code (to speed up some matrix operations), my code is something similar to this one (my real dataset is also similar to 'gps'),

```
import numpy as np
gps = [np.random.rand(50,50) for i in xrange(1000)]
ips = np.zeros( (len(gps),len(gps)), dtype='float32')

for i in xrange(len(gps)):
  for j in xrange(0,i+1):
    ips[i,j]= f.innerProd(gps[i],gps[j])
    ips[j,i]= ips[i,j]
   print "Inner product matrix: %3.0f %% done (%d of %d)"%  \
               (((i+1)**2.)/(len(gps)**2.)*100, i, len(gps))

def innerProd(mat1,mat2):
    return float(np.sum(np.dot(np.dot(mat1,mat2),mat1)))
```

What I would like to understand is ,  why is it that the program begins running fast during the first iterations and then slows down as it iterates further?  I know the question might be a bit naive but I really want to have a clearer idea of what is happening before I attempt anything else.  I already implemented my function in Fortran (leaving within the Fortran realm any for loops) and used f2py to create a dynamic lib to call the function from python, this would be the new code in python..

```
import numpy as np
import myfortranInnProd as fip

gps = [np.random.rand(50,50) for i in xrange(1000)]
ips = np.zeros( (len(gps),len(gps)), dtype='float32')

ips = fip.innerProd(gps)
```

unfortunately I only found out (surprisingly) that my fortran-python version runs 1.5 ~ 2 times slower than the first version (it is important to mention that I used MATMUL() on the Fortran implementation).  I have been googling around for a while and I believe that this "slow down" has something to do with the memory bandwidth, memory allocation or caching, given the large datasets, but I am not very sure about what is really happening behind and how could I improve the performance.  I have run the code on both a small intel atom , 2GB ram and a 4 core intel xeon, with 8GB (of course with a correspondingly scaled dataset) and the "slow down" behavior is the same.

I just need to understand why is it that this 'slow down' happens?  would it do any good if i implement the function in C ? or try to implement it to run on a GPU ?  Any other ideas how to improve it?   Thanks in advance

Comment: i ran this under `profile` and found that most of the time 307 seconds were being spent in `np.dot`; you can profile any file by doing `python -m profile filename.py`

Comment: the inner loop takes the same time if you divide it by `(i+1)`. So it behaves as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, the number of executions of the inner loop will grow each time you complete an execution of the outer loop.  When `i` is 0, the inner loop will only be executed once, but when `i` is 100, it will be executed 101 times.  Could this explain your observations, or do you mean that each execution of the inner loop itself is getting slower over time?

Comment: You are right,  it was quite obvious :D.. I should have figured it out  by myself.  Anyway,   any ideas on how to improve its performance?  Do you think a C implementation could do the job? As I understand numpy is already implemented low-level, so I don't know if it would make any difference, what do you think?  I believe I will try to implement it using pycuda.

Answer (score 2):

The number of executions of the inner `for` loop depends on the value of `i`, the index of the outer `for` loop. Since you're displaying your debug each time the inner loop finishes, it gets displayed less and less often as `i` grows. (Note that the percentage increases regularly, however.)